# Connection cannot be made ensure that the server is running SSAS and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas

I tried running SQL Server browser:

[image]

I tried a lot of things to fix this error, but no useful benefits.

Comment: we are not in a hurry. Is SSAS running on your PC ?

Comment: yes, SSAS running on my PC

Comment: and SSAS is in the multidimensional mode ?

Comment: yes  SSAS is in the multidimensional mode

Comment: Thank you very very much. solved,
the problem was ssas in services was manual, I turned it to automatic then start the sass
and worked.. thank you ♥